# Using a chipped german ID card (Personalausweis) at e-passport-gates in the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, identity-cards, german-citizens

Can I use a new, chipped german ID card (Personalausweis) at the e-passport-gates in the UK, e.g. at Heathrow airport? It has also a biometrical chip, but carries another symbol than the passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can confirm the e-gates won't take IDs, so you must approach an officer (EU or non-EU - as an EU citizen you can go wherever is quicker)

Answer (score 3):

You must use a passport to use the ePassport gates

> You’re from an EEA country and Switzerland
>
> You can use the EU/EEA
> channel to get your passport or **identity card checked** - this is
> usually faster than the other channels.
>
> You can use automatic ePassport gates at some airports if your
> **passport** has a ‘chip’ on it and you’re 12 or over. If you’re between
> 12 and 17, you must be accompanied by an adult.
>
> These gates use facial recognition technology to check your identity
> against the photo in your passport.

https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control